# Using '--Query' for getting internal attributes

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, backup

I'm working on aws backup cli commands. I found it difficult to use `--query` parameter in one of the commands. `aws backup get-backup-plan --backup-plan-id {planid}` command gives a result like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KSLk.png)
In this result I want to further use `--query` to take the BackupPlanName alone. Could anyone help me with this issue?

I tried to use `--query "BackupPlan[*].BackupPlanName"`. Its not working

Comment: " Its not working" - its not clear. What **exactly** is happening. Any errors?

Comment: It gives output as null. I need the Name as output.

Comment: You can get the name with `--query BackupPlan.BackupPlanName`